# Webservice connection data storage

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, connection

I would like to ask you how can i implement the next:

I have a tabBar where each tab make one different connection to one web service, and should show a different data. 
I would like to save this data "somewhere" and from it place load the different tabs.

Where i should save this received data?

Thank you,
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

it depends, do you want it to persist across application invocations?  If so you best bet is either an  sql3lite db or a file on the filesystem (Core Data is another option, although it would seem to be overkill in this case).  Both are fairly easy to do.  The apple iphone developers portal has examples of both.

Comment: No, i don't need to it persist across application invocations, because i receive personal data for this moment that i'm calling( next invocation the data will change)